# Is there any way to update json column?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

```
ALTER TABLE
managers
UPDATE
JSONExtractString(managers.extra_data, 'name') = JSONExtractString(other_table.extra_data, 'name')
WHERE 1
```

Query above does not work, also couldn't find something similar to `jsonb_set` function like in psql

Comment: Please mention in the tag which RDBMS as well

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictionary with `other_table` as source and then use
`JSONExtractString(dictGet('my_dict', managers.key), 'name')` to read data from dict for each specific key.
In your case there is no way to understand how to join rows in this two tables.